# Переезд с mercurial на git

Tags: git, mercurial, миграция, hg

Здравствуйте!
Есть большая проблема с переездом на git.
Почему-то переезжает только одна ветка, а их полно...
Использую TortoiseHg с плагином hggit. В hgrc меняю только path.
Прошу помочь в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Для пингвина лучше сделать вот так:**

Есть инструмент **hg-fast-export**.

Его можно найти здесь:

```
git clone http://repo.or.cz/r/fast-export.git /tmp/fast-export
```

Нужно получить mercurial репу:

```
hg clone <remote repo URL> /tmp/hg-repo
```

Далее нужно создать файл соответствия авторов.

```
cd /tmp/hg-repo
hg log | grep user: | sort | uniq | sed 's/user: *//' > ../authors
```

В */tmp/authors* будет примерно следующее содержимое:

```
bob
bob@localhost
bob <bob@company.com>
bob jones <bob <AT> company <DOT> com>
Bob Jones <bob@company.com>
Joe Smith <joe@company.com>
```

В примере выше, один и тот же человек (Боб) вносил изменения под пятью различными именами, лишь одно из которых правильное, а одно и вовсе не соответствует формату Git. hg-fast-export позволяет быстро исправить ситуацию, добавив ={new name and email address} к каждой строке, которую мы хотим изменить; чтобы оставить имя как есть, просто удалите нужные строки. Если же все имена выглядят хорошо, этот файл и вовсе не потребуется. В нашем примере мы хотим чтобы данные выглядели так:

```
bob=Bob Jones <bob@company.com>
bob@localhost=Bob Jones <bob@company.com>
bob jones <bob <AT> company <DOT> com>=Bob Jones <bob@company.com>
bob <bob@company.com>=Bob Jones <bob@company.com>
```

Затем нужно создать Git репозиторий и запустить экспорт:

```
git init /tmp/converted
cd /tmp/converted
/tmp/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r /tmp/hg-repo -A /tmp/authors
```

Флаг -r указывает на подлежащий конвертации Mercurial репозиторий, а флаг -A задаёт файл с соответствиями между авторами. Скрипт пробегается по наборам изменений Mercurial и преобразует их в скрипт для fast-import в Git.
И отправляем изменение в репу гита:

```
git remote add origin git@my-git-server:myrepository.git
git push origin --all
```

**Для винды почти так же только немного другие команды:**

```
cd c:\projects
hg clone <remote repo URL> hg-repo
git init converted
git clone http://repo.or.cz/r/fast-export.git
```

Отредактировать *c:\projects\fast-export\hg-fast-export.py*. Начало этого скрипта нужно заменить на такое:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) 2007, 2008 Rocco Rutte <pdmef@gmx.net> and others.
# License: MIT <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php>

import sys

# import mercurial libraries from zip:
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\library.zip')

from mercurial import node
from hg2git import setup_repo, fixup_user, get_branch, get_changeset
from hg2git import load_cache, save_cache, get_git_sha1, set_default_branch, set_origin_name
from optparse import OptionParser
import re
import os
```

Скопировать fast-export в converted игнорируя .git папку.
Далее: `cd converted` и создайте тут файл authors.txt по аналогии из linux версии.

И `hg-fast-export.sh -r c:\projects\hg-repo -A authors.txt`
Готово. Дальше можно заливать гит репу на сервер.

Comment: Илья огромное вам спасибо. Через hg-fast-export действительно всё прошло. Единственное пришлось применить параметр --force при экспортировании. А так всё скинулось и даже собралось после этого.
Отдельное спасибо за качественно подготовленный ответ, всё очень красиво и по делу.